# Spring boot doesn't commit changes with cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I have a very simple spring boot application that communicate with cassandra . In my sample When I run myApplication keySpace "myTestKeySpace" created but when i stop application that automatically dropped from database . what's wrong?

```java
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

public static final String KEYSPACE = "myTestKeySpace";

@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE;
}

@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(KEYSPACE);

    return Arrays.asList(specification);
}

@Override
protected List<DropKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceDrops() {
    return Arrays.asList(DropKeyspaceSpecification.dropKeyspace(KEYSPACE));
}

@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return KEYSPACE;
}

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"com.mySite"};
}
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class , args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never use Springdata with Cassandra, but I guess the method `getKeyspaceDrops` will drop the keyspace in the same manner the `getKeyspaceCreations` will create it.